# FOUND_ROWS() do MySQL é uma função que roda em relação a sessão local ou global?

Tags: mysql

Eu não entendo muito dessa questão de sessão do MySQL, porém para resolver uma necessidade tive que utilizar o comando `FOUND_ROWS()`, minha query ficou assim:

```
SELECT * FROM LICENCAS where FK_PEDIDO = 9479174 AND LICENCA_DATA_EMISSAO BETWEEN '2018-02-26 19:45:05' AND '2018-03-26 19:45:05';SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

A duvida é: Se eu colocar isso em produção, e tiver uma grande concorrência(vários usuários simultâneos executando suas queries, `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` é relacionado ao `SELECT` de cada usuário individualmente ou relacionado ao ultimo `SELECT` do servidor?

Tenho receio de acabar tendo uma assincronia e acabar executando `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` no `SELECT`  errado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua dúvida é uma preocupação válida, bom indicador de que está raciocinando para programar, antecipando situações.

As funções como `FIND_ROWS`, ultimo ID inserido e outras do mesmo tipo são praticamente todas armazenadas por **conexão**. Mesmo que seja na mesma aplicação, se você tem dois `connect` armazenados em ponteiros diferentes, cada um funciona independente do outro.

Só vai dar problema se você na mesma conexão fizer mais de uma query paralela. Por exemplo, é comum uma aplicação abrir uma conexão só, e você fazer esse tipo de query em *threads* separadas. Neste caso, melhor seria examinar o resultado retornado, usando algo da linguagem cliente, ou fazer algum tipo de serialização de comandos.

Algumas coisas devem ser notadas:

```
 SELECT coluna FROM tabela WHERE id = 100 LIMIT 20,50;

 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS coluna FROM tabela WHERE id = 100 LIMIT 20,50;
```

No caso acima, o `FOUND_ROWS` vai retornar todos os encontrados, **independentemente da clausula `LIMIT`**, quando ativa a opção `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, e respeitando o `LIMIT` no primeiro caso.

Além disso, ele deve ser usado imediatamente subsequente à *query* da qual você quer obter o valor. Note que se precisar do valor depois disso, precisa armazenar de alguma forma.

Outra coisa: se a *query* anterior deu erro, seu resultado é indefinido.

Uma situação que daria problema seria replicação baseada em comandos, e não em linhas, então o MySQL procura fazer por linha (valores):

> *FOUND_ROWS() is not replicated reliably using statement-based replication. This function is automatically replicated using row-based replication*

Manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Nota: eu até imagino que o *query planner* do MySQL seja "esperto" o suficiente para, no caso de uma *query* no formato SELECT ... ; SELECT FOUND_ROWS.. numa string só nunca dar problema, mas não quis bater muito nesta tecla pelo fato de as linguagens-cliente não incentivarem multiplas *queries* até por uma questão de segurança, e pelo fato de eu não ter encontrado nada que afirme isso oficialmente. No outro lado, se for usar o cliente de linha de comando do MySQL, é bom notar que também não vai ter problema, pois cada instância é uma conexão, de qualquer forma.

Comment: Muito boa sua explicação ! Mas eu tenho uma pergunta, você diz que `FOUND_ROWS` vai retornar tudo encontrado independente do `LIMIT`, eu executei `SELECT * FROM LICENCAS where FK_PEDIDO = 9479174 AND LICENCA_DATA_EMISSAO BETWEEN '2018-02-26 19:45:05' AND '2018-03-26 19:45:05' LIMIT 0,100;SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` a consulta do `FOUND_ROWS` sem `LIMIT` me retornava `105` com o `LIMIT`me retornou `100` certinho.

Comment: Isso quer dizer que a opção `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` está desativada?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti a sintaxe é SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ..... para ativar a opção. (você acrescenta a flag logo em seguida do select) - Editei a resposta esclarecendo melhor

Comment: Nossa ! Boa, me ajudou MUITO.